# how to replace certain value of a dataframe column by iterating

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

Good evening please I work on a dataframe of energy consumption of all countries recognized by the UN.
my problem is that i want to change the name of some country in the column Energy_df ["Country"]. So I put
the countries which I wanted to replace as a key in a dictionary and the new names as values. but when i make my code i notice that only the first name is changed. so I would like to know how to apply it to other country names in the dictionary

```
# Energy_df["Country"] is the dataset column which I want to replace certain country name 

newname={"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America": "United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}

def answer():
    for name in Energy_df["Country"]:
        if name in newname.key():
            Energy_df["Country"].replace(newname[name],inplace=True)
        else:
            continue
    return Energy_df["Country"]
answer()
```

Comment: `Energy_df['Country'] = Energy_df['Country'].replace(newname)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace` of series.

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].replace(newname)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but I don't want to replace all the country names which are in the column df ['Country'] only some country names which I took care to put in a dictionary and the keys of the dictionaries are the country names which I want to replace and the key values ​​are the new name of this country.

Comment: That’s exactly what `replace` does, as also commented. Did you try?

Comment: whaoo this is extraordinary. your method is correct and it works well. I did not notice that the give was changed as planned. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` to map your dictionary keys to the values:

```py
newname={"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America": "United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}

df = pd.DataFrame([{
    'Country': "Republic of Korea"
},{
    'Country': "United States of America"
}])
print(df.head())
#                     Country
# 0         Republic of Korea
# 1  United States of America
df['Country'] = df['Country'].map(newname)
print(df.head())
#          Country
# 0    South Korea
# 1  United States
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but I don't want to replace all the country names which are in the column df ['Country'] only some country names which I took care to put in a dictionary and the keys of the dictionaries are the country names which I want to replace and the key values ​​are the new name of this country.

Comment: Same as @Gilseung-Ahn said about `replace`, it will only map the values that are in the dictionary to the new value.